# Doing a assignment in python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to do an assignment operation in python single line for loop
like

```
[a[i]=b[i] for i in range(0,len(b))]
```

This seems wrong. Is there a way I can use assignment operation in python single line for loop?

Comment: Btw., what you are using is not a for loop but a list comprehension.

Comment: Do `a` and `b` have the same length? And what is your use-case? Maybe there's an even better way (without loops or comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two paradigms here, that of loop and list comprehension. The list comprehension will be

```
a = [x for x in b]
```

Comment: or why not `a = b[:]`

Comment: Does the same, but I think OP is trying to learn list comprehension as an alternative to looping over list. This explicitly conveys the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Copy lists can be done in many ways in Python.

- Using slicing

  a = b[:]
- Using `list()`

  a = list(b)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop. You can use a slice assignment:

```
a[0:len(b)]= b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
[a.__setitem__(i, b[i]) for i in range(0,len(b))]
```

the `__setitem__` is the method that implements index-assignment. However doing a list comprehension only because of side-effects is a big no-no.

You could simply use slice-assignment:

```
a[:len(b)] = b
```

Answer (score 0):

**in python 3** it can be done by:

```
a = b.copy()
```